# Need Advice: Latest version of Node.js vs using Synaptic Package Manager?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying to get node.js and npm installed on my Ubuntu 11.10 installation, and I'm having a tricky time. I decided to go the route of downloading and compiling from the latest source because I want to use the new version of node.js - v0.6.0 instead of the older version that the synaptic package manager will install. However, I could not get npm set up correctly with it due to a "module not found" error. I was completely surprised at how little information I was able to find on the error.

Anyways, my goal here is to learn node.js, not to run a production environment. Should I give in and use v4.9 or is it really worth getting the newest version for the sake of learning, even if I have to go through the pain of keeping it updated and configuring it myself?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? NPM is compatible with Node v 6.0.

Comment: Actually, I just fixed it by completely purging everything node-related, then installing node from source and npm from it's one-line install. But I'm still interested in opinions on whether it's better practice to use synaptic to manage node/npm or to have the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you want to install node from source since the packages you find in package managers are usually out of date. 0.4.12 was the last stable before 0.6.0 that was released a few days ago. 0.4.9 is pretty out of date.

Comment: Anyone wishing to install from source should should put some consideration into the trouble it will introduce: no easy way to uninstall, increases difficulty of upgrades, the packaged version of node will be installed if you install any packages depending on it. Using a backported package is IMHO a much better solution.

Comment: @Martin Updating node is as simple as pulling from or checking out whatever branch you need from the git repo and running `make install` again. Uninstalling is just running `make uninstall`. Granted, this is more difficult than using package managers, but it's not *that* much worse.

Answer (score 7):

If you have Ubuntu, install it from Chris Lea's repo, it's always up to date with the last stable version (for ex now the version is 0.6.0 - as of today):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Two years later, and this is still the best method for installing up to date nodejs via apt-get.  It helped me resolve some issues with meteorite smart packages, where meteorite required a newer version of node than I had.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question, nowadays my preferred way to install node is by using nvm (Node Version Manager). This will allow you to have multiple versions of node installed and quickly switch version.

**Installation:**

Install C++ compiler

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
```

Install NVM

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.2/install.sh | bash
source ~/.profile
```

Install node (select which version you want to install)

```
nvm install 6
```

**Usage:**

To set a default node version:

```
nvm alias default 0.12.7
```

To select a different installed version:

```
nvm use 4
```